# How to change direction of one column of datagridview from right to left?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have below code in asp.net datagrid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStore" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" EmptyDataText="هیچ کالایی موجود نیست"
                            Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            Width="1000px" OnRowDataBound="gvStore_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvStore_SelectedIndexChanging" 
                            OnPageIndexChanging="gvStore_PageIndexChanging" CaptionAlign="Right" DataKeyNames="store_id"> 
                            <PagerSettings FirstPageText="ابتدا" LastPageText="انتها" Mode="NumericFirstLast"
                                NextPageText="بعدی" PreviousPageText="قبلی" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="rownum" HeaderText="ردیف" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="store_id" HeaderText="شناسه" Visible="False" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="groups_name" HeaderText="نام کالا"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="str" HeaderText="مشخصات کالا"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="plaque_no1" HeaderText="شماره اموال 1"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="plaque_no2" HeaderText="شماره اموال 2"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="buy_request_no" HeaderText="شماره درخواست" ></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="contract_no" HeaderText="شماره قرارداد"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="تاریخ ورود" DataField="bdate"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="محل بودجه" DataField="budjet_name"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:CommandField SelectText="جزئیات درخواست" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

How can I change direction of one column of this to right to left?
could anyone help me please ?

Comment: Question will closed soon, unless you provide necessary information

Answer (score 2):

you can use below to change text direction from **right to left**.

```
GridView1.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction] = "rtl";
```

**Particular Cell**

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction] = "rtl";
```

For **Left to Right**

```
GridView1.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction] = "ltr";

GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction] = "ltr";
```

[here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1117791/3607179.aspx) is the link for full reference.

Comment: but i want for specific column

Comment: @FatemehHojjati using above code, you can manipulate your cells at run time in `RowDataBound` event.. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) is the reference.

Comment: @FatemehHojjati you would need to fix your server side issue... and make sure you are changing orientation for right cell..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this `css`

This `css` save me :

```
.gridalign
{
   width:auto;
   text-align:right;
   direction:ltr;

   padding-right:15px;
   padding-left:15px;
}
```